# Nice seo URLs in CakePhp

Tags: url, cakephp, url-rewriting, url-routing

I'm developing website on CakePhp, and I have next problem with URLs.

In my app for categories and subcategories pages I need have next URLs:

- /category-slug/
- /category-slug/subcategory-slug

and problem is that this format of URLs matching with any *controller/action* URL, and I can't just hardcode all category/subcategory urls, because there are a lot of them, and they are dynamic.

How this can be solved?

**Edit**

I found this approach http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp, but maybe exists something that not requires additional checks in db, cache etc?

Answer (score 1):

Quickest/easiest way:

```
// routes.php
Router::connect('/category/:category/:subcategory', 
                     array('controller'=>'categories', 'action'=>'view'), 
                     array('pass' => array('category', 'subcategory')));

// CategoryController/view
public function view($category = 'default', $subcategory = null) {
    // your logic here
}

// links
$this->Html->link('View PHP >> Tutorials', array('action'=>'view', 
                       'category'=>'php', 'subcategory'=>'tutorials')); 

// output
<a href="/category/php/tutorials">View PHP >> Tutorials</a>
```

by introducing the `/category/` at the start, you don't need to worry about providing a route for every other controller/action (otherwise every request will get sent to your category controller.

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking for solution without any additional parts of URL before or after "/category/subcategory". It's a commercial project, and such URLs a quite crucial part of the website.

Comment: [this post](http://lecterror.com/articles/view/advanced-routing-with-cakephp-one-example) might be of some use to you; but otherwise I am unaware of any other way to achieve this without providing a route every possible request.